# Trying to move an Iframe up

Tags: css, wordpress, iframe

I'm attempting to add additional CSS to WordPress to move an iframe up using Bottom: and changing it from 28px to 71px and I can't for the life of me get it to work.

[image]

The CSS I've tried adding is:

```
.LeadBoosterContainer{
     bottom: 50px !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "bottom" property only really works when a position property other than "static"(which is the default) is set.
What you may want to use is margins. Either a **margin-bottom** or a negative **margin-top**.
Margin-bottom will give the iframe space to the next element below it.
A negative margin-top will basically "pull" it up, which sounds like it is what you are trying to do.

If you want to use the bottom property however, you will need to play with positioning.
Here you can read up on how the bottom property works depending on the position-property: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_bottom.asp

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by referencing the div id pipedrive-chat-holder below

```
#LeadboosterContainer.proactiveChat{
     bottom: 80px !important;
}
```